# Fill table depending dropdown list selected value in Laravel vuejs Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to get data in the table  code are as below
I want to autofill the table with the depending dropdownlist selected value. i’ve been finding solution since days but didn’t get any success. I’m very new at this.
If anyone could help to get me out from this issue i’ll be very grateful. Thank You.

Here Is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">employees Table</h3>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="md-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <select
                    name="company_id"
                    id="company_id"
                    :class="{'is-invalid':form.errors.has('company_id')}"
                    class="form-control"
                    v-model="form.company_id"
                    @change="getEmployeesbyCompany()"
                  >
                    <option value selected>Select Company</option>
                    <option
                      v-for="Company in Companies.data"
                      :key="Company.id"
                    >{{Company.Company}}</option>
                  </select>
                  <has-error :form="form" field="company_id"></has-error>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-header -->
      <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <!-- <thead>

          </thead>-->
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Badge#</th>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>BadgeType</th>
              <th>Nationality</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Telphonenumber</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>SupervisorName</th>
              <th>SupervisorNumber</th>
              <th>Issuedate</th>
              <th>Tazker</th>
              <th>Expiredate</th>
              <th>Serialnumber</th>
              <th>Modify</th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="employee in employees.data" :key="employee.id">
              <td>{{employee.id}}</td>

              <td>{{employee.BadgeCode|UppCaseFirstLetter}}</td>
              <!-- <td>{{employee.company_id}}</td> -->
              <td>{{Company.Company}}</td>
              <td>
                <span class="tag tag-success">{{employee.BadgeType}}</span>
              </td>
              <td>{{Nationality.nationality}}</td>

              <td>{{employee.lastname |UppCaseFirstLetter}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.firstname |UppCaseFirstLetter}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.telphonenumber |UppCaseFirstLetter}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.position |UppCaseFirstLetter}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.supervisorname |UppCaseFirstLetter}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.supervisornumber|UppCaseFirstLetter}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.Issuedate|mydate}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.tazker|UppCaseFirstLetter}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.Expiredate |mydate}}</td>
              <td>{{employee.serialnumber |UppCaseFirstLetter}}</td>


            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
      <div class="card-footer">
        <pagination :data="employees" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
  </div>
```

My @change="getEmployeesbyCompany" method:

```
 methods: {
         getEmployeesbyCompany: function() {
         axios.get("api/getEmployees", {
         params: {company_id: this.form.company_id}})
         .then( function(response) {this.employees = response.data;}.bind(this)
          );
         }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('getEmployees','API\EmployeeController@getEmployees');
```

My getEmployees(){} method:

```
public function getEmployees(Request $request)
{

      $employees = Employee::where('company_id',$request->company_id)->get();

     return $employees;

}
```

My data() in Vue Component:

```
 data() {    
          return {      
                   editMode: false,
                  selectedTicketInvoiceId: false,
                  Companies: {},

                  Nationalities: {},
                  employees: {},
                  form: new Form({id: "",BadgeCode: "",BadgeType: "",company_id: "",
                                   nationality_id: "",lastname: "",firstname: "",telphonenumber: "",
                                   position: "",supervisorname: "", supervisornumber: "",
                                   issuedate: "",tazker: "", expiredate: "", serialnumber: "" })};
     }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Or what is the result of the code you've posted?

Comment: I could not get the data

Comment: if the above code is wrong please let me know the correct code to get the data and show it in table regarding dropdown list selected value

Comment: As far as I can tell, your controller function is not setting a property named `data` anywhere. So why are you using `employees.data` in your `v-for` directive?

Comment: when I load the form at the first time the table is also loaded with data but what I want is when I select the company_id from dropdownlist the table should load the data depending dropdownlist selected value employss.data is not a problem

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.

Comment: is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200402/discussion-between-mohammad-usman-and-vince).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your table is using `employees.data` in the `v-for` directive. This works fine on the initial page load, because `employees` is a Laravel paginator, so the `data` property is defined, and it contains the array of employees, as expected.

However, your controller function is simply returning an array of employees. You are saving that array to your Vue instance's `employees` property. So now `employees.data` is undefined, and your table is empty.

To fix the issue, you can update your controller function like this:

```
public function getEmployees(Request $request)
{
  $employees = Employee::where('company_id',$request->company_id)->get();

  return ['data' => $employees]; // or return response()->json(['data' => employees]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I could not express my happiness it worked for me.

Comment: Glad I could help!